# How to keep the default light while adding another?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, lighting

When creating a 3D scene (or subscene) a default light is added:

> A default headlight will be added to a scene that contains one or more Shape3D nodes, but no light nodes. This light source is a Color.WHITE PointLight placed at the camera position.

When adding a custom light source to the scene or any child the default light is removed. How do I keep the default light and add other lights in addition to it? Do I have to manually add a `new PointLight()` to the root group?